# No puedo invocar un Reporte rdlc Tampoco Crystal Report en Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Disculpen la molestia se que aun soy nuevo en estoy pero necesito sus ayudas estoy tratando de poder mostrar un reporte web en asp.net de vb, Pero no lo he logrado debido a que el reporte no lo puedo llamar desde un Método ni de una clase tampoco puedo pasar valores como parámetro Aquí les dejo mi Script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

te adjunto la forma como trabajo reportes de [crystal-report](/questions/tagged/crystal-report) y como paso los parametros.

[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
    </div>
</form>
```

[vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net)

```
Dim rpt As New rptNombreDelReporte
rpt.SetParameterValue("@Parametro", "ValorParametro")
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
```

espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo había probado de esa manera pero igual salia el error al parecer era porque faltaba una dll del crystal report
De antemano gracias por la respuesta.